# Identify the marked cell row ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to implement the select alarm day page, like the alarm screen in iPhone. I can mark multiple cells at a time but the problem is that when I mark row 1 & 2 I can't identify that the two rows are marked. Can anyone help me?

here is the screen, that I have implemented [image: image here]]

```
NSUserDefaults *dd=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


  UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

if (path.row==0) {
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;



    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


        [dd setObject:@"sun" forKey:@"key"];

        day=@"sun";


    }

}
if (path.row==1) {
    if (Tablcell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        Tablcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        day=@"mon";
            [dd setObject:@"mon" forKey:@"key"];

    }

[dd synchronize];
}
```

Comment: When you want to check which rows are marked ?

Comment: When I am pressing back button i want to get the marked row values .

Comment: It looks the back button is of navigation item. You can check when it is pressed but its a different story. You can do one thing. It looks your multipleSelection is enabled. You can check the **indexPathsForSelectedRows** in the method **viewWillDisappear**. Or add a custom back button, add a method to it and when it is pressed check ** indexPathsForSelectedRows**.

Comment: how to check the indexPathsForSelectedRows in the method viewWillDisappear.I am not used these methods

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear?language=objc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Step: 1**

Create a mutual array

```
NSMutableArray *selectedIndexArray;
```

**Step : 2**
In didSelectItemAtIndexPath Method add index value in selectedIndexArray

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.item];
[selectedIndexArray addObject:str];
```

**Step : 3**
In didDeselectItemAtIndexPath Method remove index value from selectedIndexArray

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.item];
if([selectedIndexArray containsObject:str]){

        [selectedIndexArray removeObject:str];
}
```

**Step : 4**

Now you can use this array to show / hide checked button in cell